# Open a second form while automatically closing the first form

Tags: c#, forms

I created a login form in c#.

If a user signs in with the right password and username and clicks on 'Login' then the second form opens. How do I close the login form after the last step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your Main() method in Program.cs to display the login dialog.  Don't start the message loop unless a valid login was entered.  For example:

```
static void Main() {
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  using (var login = new LoginForm()) {
    if (login.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
  }
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Your LoginForm should set its DialogResult property to OK if it detected a proper login.

Answer (score 0):

You can type

```
FormName.ActiveForm.Close();
```

It closes the current active form.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `this.Close();`

Answer (score 0):

I would do a ShowDialog() of the Login Form from the main form.

After the login form closes you are back in the main form.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var foo = new Form() { Text = "Login" };
        if (foo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           ...
        }
    }
```