# My form is not opening in STA

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm trying to open my main form, from my login form.

```
Application.Run(new Form1(usernameText.Text));
```

But it's not opening in STA.. So my `folderBrowserDialog1` in my main form won't open. And I have `[STAThread]` in my program.cs just above `static void Main()` And it still does not work... So I'm not sure what to do...

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new loginForm());
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What happens?

Comment: I'm not positive but I *think* calling `Application.Run()` twice is a bad thing. Not sure if that's causing your problem or not. If so, you can use `Form.Show()`, and use the no-argument version of `Application.Run()` (just make sure to use `Application.Exit()` when your main form closes).

Comment: @SLaks This happens: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.

Comment: Use [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20645518/1159478) to your last question, rather than the one that you accepted.  You're now running two message loops, one inside of the other.  That's...generally something to avoid.

Comment: Where is your code running? What's the call stack?

Comment: @Servy Ok.. But how can I make my login form return a DialogResult as yes??

Comment: @StianTofte On the login form set it to whatever it should be, based on what happened.  Have a value that you set for a successful login, another for cancelling, etc.  It's just a property that you can set to whatever you want.  You can use your own custom property if you want, but since the existing one generally fits the purpose you're trying to serve, there's really no need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a second form while automatically closing the first form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020261/open-a-second-form-while-automatically-closing-the-first-form)

Comment: @Servy okay. I fixed it by doing it in the program.cs. So I marked your answer as correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Servy's response to your [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645476/open-a-new-form-on-the-main-thread/20645518#20645518):

Go to your program.cs file and alter it so that you show your login form.  Then, after it has been closed, determine if you should open up another form.

It'll likely look something like this:

```
LoginForm loginform = new LoginForm();
Application.Run(loginform);

if (loginform.DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
//TODO handle error cases
```